# Olá gostaria de saber como posso salvar o resultado desse gerador em um .txt agradeço se tiver um breve explicação obrigado!

Tags: python

def cpf_generate():

```
while True:
    cpf = [randint(0, 9) for i in range(9)]
    if cpf != cpf[::-1]:
        break


for i in range(9, 11):
    value = sum((cpf[num] * ((i + 1) - num) for num in range(0, i)))
    digit = ((value * 10) % 11) % 10
    cpf.append(digit)


result =''.join(map(str, cpf))
return result
```

opcao = int(input('''[1] Validar um CPF
[2] Gerar um CPF válido
Opção: '''))
if opcao == 1:
cpf = input('Digite o CPF: ')
if cpf_validate(cpf):
print('CPF válido. ')
else:
print('CPF inválio. ')
elif opcao == 2:
cpf = cpf_generate()
if cpf_validate(cpf):
print(f'CPF GERADO!: {cpf[:3]}.{cpf[3:6]}.{cpf[6:9]}-{cpf[9:]}')
else:
print('Inválido.')

Comment: O título precisa ser mais curto e específico, o que voce colocou no título pode ser a primeira frase na descrição. Tem parte do teu código que não está indentado.

Answer (score 0):

Para salvar o resultado do gerador de CPF num arquivo .txt, basta adicionar uma linha de código para abrir o arquivo em modo de escrita e outra linha para escrever o resultado nele. Aqui está um exemplo de como isso poderia ser feito:

```
def cpf_generate():
    # Código do gerador aqui...

opcao = int(input('''[1] Validar um CPF [2] Gerar um CPF válido Opção: '''))
if opcao == 1:
    cpf = input('Digite o CPF: ')
    if cpf_validate(cpf):
        print('CPF válido. ')
    else:
        print('CPF inválio. ')
elif opcao == 2:
    cpf = cpf_generate()
    if cpf_validate(cpf):
        # Abra o arquivo em modo de escrita
        with open("resultado.txt", "w") as arquivo:
            # Escreva o resultado no arquivo
            arquivo.write(cpf)
        print(f'CPF GERADO!: {cpf[:3]}.{cpf[3:6]}.{cpf[6:9]}-{cpf[9:]}')
    else:
        print('Inválido.')
```

A função open cria um novo arquivo chamado "resultado.txt" e retorna um objeto de arquivo que pode ser usado para escrever dados nele. O parâmetro "w" especifica que o arquivo deve ser aberto em modo de escrita.

ou

```
# Crie o gerador
def cpf_generate():
  while True:
      cpf = [randint(0, 9) for i in range(9)]
      if cpf != cpf[::-1]:
          break

  for i in range(9, 11):
      value = sum((cpf[num] * ((i + 1) - num) for num in range(0, i)))
      digit = ((value * 10) % 11) % 10
      cpf.append(digit)

  result =''.join(map(str, cpf))
  return result

# Abra o arquivo em modo de escrita
with open("resultado.txt", "w") as arquivo:
  # Gere e escreva o CPF no arquivo
  cpf = cpf_generate()
  arquivo.write(cpf)
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado ! s2

Comment: funcionou cara eu tinha errado no with open("resultado.txt", "w") as arquivo:
pq juntei com o exemplo de cima mais depois q tirei ele salvou sem erros s2. so agradeço ter pessoas que nem vcs abraço!

Comment: Que bom que ajudou, abraço!